# manipulating data in memory using c/c++ pointer

Tags: c, visual-c++

**manipulating data using pointer.**
manipulating the data of one process using another process.i did try in c and c++ using pointer ,but not successful.please tell how to do or give some reference.

because one of my friend try to edit the score of the counter trick game while playing.So i feel it is possible but i did something wrong.

Comment: You can't manipulate data in one process from another process, at least on modern desktop systems. Read about other [Inter Process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You _can_ (for example, by using [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows), but it's not as simple as just using a pointer.

Comment: Did you read posts such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244912/open-process-with-debug-privileges-and-read-write-memory?rq=1

Comment: Use shared memory.  Only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current running process can't access the memory of any other process.

Each Process in Windows has its own address space. When you have an addresss in one process it is a virtual address and meaningless with the corresponding page table. When Windows performs the task switch the next task gets its own page table.

The access to other memory is protected so you can't modify the page table from your process. You need the debugger API to access the memory of another process.

One exception is the Windows Kernel. When you are in a kernel mode driver your have more rights and a different API that allows this access. (And you have addition headache to implement such a driver.)